# .htaccess simulate directories

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect /services/websites.html to just websites.html in my head directory. That way I will be able to put all my files in the head directory so all css files and stuff like that will be linked correctly. I tried:

RewriteRule ^services/websites.html$ websites.html

But that does not work. I figured it is something simple but I couldn't find anything on Google.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you need to put in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^services/(.*)$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteRule ^.*websites\.html$ websites.html
```

Please note the html not hmtl in your example.

Comment: It works, but the CSS file doesn't link, do I have to add an RewriteRule for that too?

Comment: ok, you probably need to rewrite everything, since the URL inside the HTML page points to the same baseURL. If every page points to the services folder you could use what @anubhava is writeing